# Add prefix/suffix to multiple columns of dfs in a list

Tags: r

I've stumbled upon this problem and would be very much obliged if someone could help me. Also, this is my first time posting, so bear with me.

**EDIT:** The old reproducible sample I've provided was misleading because it suggested that the column names follow a pattern as in X1, X2, X3, etc. I have updated the sample now.

I have a list of 20 data frames. The number of columns is always the same, but the number of rows differs slightly. I would like to change the column names of each data frame by adding a suffix or prefix from `2000` to `20XX` to the last four columns - which is to say every column but the first one, which will act as a key for merging.

Below I've created a reproducible sample:

```
a <- data.frame(items = sample(LETTERS,5,replace=FALSE),  
                sth = sample(0:10, 10,rep=TRUE),
                here = sample(0:10, 10,rep=TRUE),
                well = sample(0:10, 10,rep=TRUE))
b <- data.frame(items = sample(LETTERS,5,replace=FALSE),  
                sth = sample(0:10, 10,rep=TRUE),
                here = sample(0:10, 10,rep=TRUE),
                well = sample(0:10, 10,rep=TRUE))
c <- data.frame(items = sample(LETTERS,5,replace=FALSE),  
                sth = sample(0:10, 10,rep=TRUE),
                here = sample(0:10, 10,rep=TRUE),
                well = sample(0:10, 10,rep=TRUE))

list_raw <- list(a, b, c)
```

The end product should look like this:

```
A <- data.frame(items = sample(LETTERS, 5, replace = FALSE),
                sth_2000 = sample(0:10, 10,rep=TRUE),
                here_2000 = sample(0:10, 10,rep=TRUE),
                well_2000 = sample(0:10, 10,rep=TRUE))
B <- data.frame(items = sample(LETTERS, 5, replace = FALSE),
                sth_2001 = sample(0:10, 10,rep=TRUE),
                here_2001 = sample(0:10, 10,rep=TRUE),
                well_2001 = sample(0:10, 10,rep=TRUE))
C <- data.frame(items = sample(LETTERS, 5, replace = FALSE),
                sth_2002 = sample(0:10, 10,rep=TRUE),
                here_2002 = sample(0:10, 10,rep=TRUE),
                well_2002 = sample(0:10, 10,rep=TRUE))
list_not_so_raw_anymore <- list(A, B, C)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: heads-up!! do NOT call your list `list` !! it is a function name!!

Comment: So in your example the new column names would be X1_2000, X2_2001, X3_2002, X4_2003, X5_2004, with items being untouched?

Comment: No, columns of the same df should get the same prefix. So for df A, it's X1_2000, X2_2000, X3_2000, etc.; for df B, it's X1_2001, X2_2001, X3_2001, etc.; and for df B, it's X1_2003, X2_2003, X3_2003, etc. In every case, items should be left untouched.

Comment: You should change the example code you posted, it's not illustrating that.

Comment: @norie updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with something similar to akrun's code.

```
a <- data.frame(items = sample(LETTERS,5,replace=FALSE),  
                replicate(5,sample(0:10, 10,rep=TRUE)))
b <- data.frame(items = sample(LETTERS,5,replace=FALSE),  
                replicate(5,sample(0:10, 15,rep=TRUE)))
c <- data.frame(items = sample(LETTERS,5,replace=FALSE),  
                replicate(5,sample(0:10, 20,rep=TRUE)))

list_raw <- list(a, b, c)

list_new <- lapply(seq_along(list_raw), function(i) {
                   y<-1999+i
                   setNames(list_raw[[i]], paste0(colnames(list_raw[[i]]), c('',paste0('_', rep(y, ncol(list_raw[[i]])-1)))))
                   })

list_new
```

Comment: This is very close to what I'm trying to do, but the columns of the same df should get the same prefix. So for df A, it's X1_2000, X2_2000, X3_2000, etc.; for df B, it's X1_2001, X2_2001, X3_2001, etc.; and for df B, it's X1_2003, X2_2003, X3_2003, etc. In every case, items and the should be left untouched.

Also, my reproducible sample suggests that the column names follow a pattern, which is misleading. Will update that.

Answer (score 0):

In `base R`, we can loop over the `list`, use `setNames` to change the column names by creating new column names with `paste` and `seq`

If it should be the same suffix, use `Map`

```
Map(function(x, y) setNames(x, c("items", 
  paste0(names(x)[-1],  "_", rep(y, length(x) - 1)))),
     list_raw,  seq(2000,
         length.out = length(list_raw), by = 1))
```

-output

```
[[1]]
   items sth_2000 here_2000 well_2000
1      C        5         1         4
2      J        2         3         7
3      Q        1         0         6
4      F        6         7         1
5      Y        2         6         6
6      C        6         1         2
7      J        4         2         2
8      Q       10         6         8
9      F        8         4         4
10     Y       10        10        10

[[2]]
   items sth_2001 here_2001 well_2001
1      G       10         9         6
2      H        7         8         6
3      J        6         1         2
4      S        9         7         7
5      A        0         6        10
6      G        1         5         3
7      H        7         2         6
8      J        3         0         9
9      S        4         6        10
10     A       10         7         8

[[3]]
   items sth_2002 here_2002 well_2002
1      Y        5         7         1
2      J        2         9         3
3      M        4         8         2
4      H       10         0         0
5      S       10         7         3
6      Y        5         7         3
7      J        7         4         2
8      M        4         2         8
9      H        9         7         6
10     S        8         1        10
```

Comment: Your solution would have worked if the column names of interest entailed the same names, which they, unfortunately, do not. I'll update the reproducible sample Sry!

Comment: @blue-create So, do you have column names with suffix numbers that needs to be changed?

Comment: Thanks for the swift response, but the current code imposes the same name to every column of a df. I have column names without any suffix or prefix numbers. Thus, I want to add a suffix/prefix number to every column name of every dataset but the item one.

Comment: @blue-create it is updated again.  I didn't see your updated data earlier.

Comment: @blue-create I don't find any difference now with your expected output

Answer (score 0):

If you know you want to only use the last 4 columns, you can also hard code the values you want to use and use lapply and `library(data.table)` to solve re-name the last four columns.

```
library(data.table)

vals <- c(2000:2003)
lapply(list_raw, 
function(f) setnames(f, 
            old = tail(names(f), 4), 
            new = paste0(vals, "_", tail(names(f), 4))))
```